# Make Speech in Safari read different languages

Tags: safari, language, text-to-speech

It would make sense when I have Safari read Japanese text (for example on [this page](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56620/why-is-%E3%81%B5%E3%81%A8%E3%82%93%E3%81%8C%E3%81%B5%E3%81%A8%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0-a-pun)) by clicking **Edit** then **Speech** then **Start Speaking**, that it would recognize Japanese language and switch voice to a Japanese voice.

However, it reads the text in the default U.S. voice and says "Hiragana Letter Hu, Hiragana Letter...".

In the Voice Utility app, I have selected default voices for Japanese:

[image]

I'm sure there's a way for the System to recognize a language and attribute the appropriate Speech Voice, without changing the whole OS' language (just the same way iPod Shuffle can [automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBIeT.png) read out the names of the tracks in different languages), ***but how do I do this***?

Answer (score 5):

I would say this is a bug in macOS, so I've reported it.

But there's a simple workaround: use *Automator* to create a simple *Service* to speak the selected text in a voice of your choice.

[image: automator service to speak text using the female Japanese voice]

You may also want to make sure to download the *enhanced quality* versions of the voice you choose to use through *System Preferences > Accessibility*:

[image: download enhanced quality voice]

If you select some text and option- or right-click to bring up the context menu, choose the *Services* menu item and you will see your custom *Speak (Japanese)* service that you can choose to read the text in that language with your chosen voice:

[image: custom service menu item]